# Immediately Executing .net application in Win CE after boot

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, compact-framework, windows-ce

I want to execute our application which is written in Compact Framework immediately after WinCE OS is boot. We already have this feature. But the problem is I am able to see the WinCE desktop for 2-3 seconds before the application starts running, I don't want this to happen.
User of our system should not see the desktop. What could be reason? does this mean that it is taking some time to initialize compact framework?

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that Windows CE starts explorer.exe first. You just have to set up your application to start before explorer.exe (and occupy the whole screen as fast as possible after that). If this can be done by [editing the registry](http://migs-winembedded.blogspot.com/2007/04/how-to-auto-run-application-after.html), you are saved. But I've seen devices where it could be only done by disabling explorer.exe to run at all.

Comment: I'd really like to see more on this, if you have it. Even more links. The one above seems to have code that doesn't match with the text descriptions, and it doesn't say what the magic numbers in HEX are for.

Comment: I just rechecked the link. The mismatch is probably caused because the code is about starting the application and the description is about other processes already set up to run automatically. AFAIK the magic numbers are dependencies for previous launch levels, so the application won't started until the previous is. I might be wrong on that part.

Comment: and I'll look into the device I've worked with as soon as possible and try to provide more information, but as I recall it used the same registry settings.

Comment: Checked and yes, this device of mine uses the same registry settings that the one provided by the linked blog post.